# send data to Observable in rx android

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I have observable like this:

```
final Observable<Model> ModelObservable=Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Model>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Model> subscriber) {
            return fetchFrom(url);
        }
    });
```

can I send url to my observable everytime I want to subscribe it?

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap this call in a method you will be able to pass the URL to the method.

```
private void callWithUrl(final String url) {
  final Observable<Model> ModelObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Model>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super Model> subscriber) {
      return fetchFrom(url);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Its considered bad practice to use create() since you then should provide backpressure functionality.